# Partial ScrollView - XML Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I've a lot of rows in my layout and I need a partial scrollview. I want fix the linearlayout and the first tablerow and a Scrollview for the remainder. Now, I've this code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout>

        <TextView
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TableRow
            >

        <TextView
            />

        <TextView
            />

        <TextView
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableLayout
        >

    <TableRow
            >
        <TextView
                />
        <TextView
                />
        <TextView
                />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
            >
        <TextView
                />
        <TextView
                />
        <TextView
                />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But doesn't compile. How should I use scrollview to achieve my goal?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- At the very least you need to define `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` in each XML element for it to compile.
- A layout can only contain 1 parent element.  You need to wrap the whole thing in a `LinearLayout` or whatever layout fits your needs.